# Definition of functional derivative with dirac delta function

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, functional-calculus

In this [book](https://www.docdroid.net/esgwpBm/quantumfieldtheoryforthegiftedamateur.pdf), the functional derivative of a functional $F[f]$ is defined as
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)} = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{F[f(y)+\epsilon \delta(y-x)] - F[f(y)]}{\epsilon}$$

It then proceeds to say that the functional derivative tells you how the number returned by the functional $F[f(x)]$ changes as you slightly change the function $f(x)$ that you feed into the machine (the author defined a functional as a machine that returns a number if given an input function).

Based on this explanation of the functional derivative, shouldn't its definition be something like

$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)} = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{F[f(y)+\epsilon \delta(y)] - F[f(y)]}{\epsilon}$$
instead? Now it makes sense because the function feeded into the machine is slightly changed to $f^{'}(x)=f(x)+\epsilon \delta(x)$.

Why is there an extra variable in the $\epsilon \delta(y-x)$ term in the author's definition of the functional derivative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer but let me give it a shot. For functionals such as

\begin{align}
F\left[y(x)\right]=\int_{0}^{1}y^{2}(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

We are familiar with determining the first variation

\begin{align}
\delta F=F\left[y+\delta y\right]-F\left[y\right]+\mathcal{O}\left(||\delta y||^{2}\right)
\end{align}

For this problem $\delta F=\int_{0}^{1} 2y\delta y\mathrm{d}x$. We want to define the functional derivative $\delta F/\delta y$ in the following way
\begin{align}
\delta F =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}\delta y\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

To finish this explanation I now make a change of notation $\delta y=\varepsilon \psi(x)$, I will also change the variable of integration $x\to s$.

\begin{align}
F\left[y+\varepsilon\psi\right]-F\left[y\right]=\varepsilon\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(s)\psi(s)\mathrm{d}s+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^{2})
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(s)\psi(s)\mathrm{d}s=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{F\left[y+\varepsilon\psi\right]-F\left[y\right]}{\varepsilon}
\end{align*}

To obtain $(\delta F/\delta y)(x)$, we simply need to use the sampling function $\psi(s)=\delta(s-x)$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}(s)\delta(s-x)\mathrm{d}s=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{F\left[y+\varepsilon\delta(s-x)\right]-F\left[y\right]}{\varepsilon}
\end{align*}

I hope that helps.